# Fetching and printing a single value from database using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently trying to create my settings page by creating a table settings with company_name column. My idea is to fetch the single value company_name and print it in the title of the pages and where the name is going to be appearing. I just am not sure how to convert the array return from the DB::select to be able to print it correctly.

The code:

```
public function __construct()
{ 
    $company_name = DB::table('settings')->select('company_name')->get();

    return View::share('company_name', $company_name);
}
```

And print it in the blade system as {{ $company_name }}, although it can't convert an array to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use eloquent (that I would recommend) which would be like this :

```
$company_name = Setting::first()->company_name;
```

or using fluent :

```
$company_name = DB::table('settings')->company_name;
```

Comment: Awesome! I was actually close to that one using Eloquent with

   $company_name = Setting::where('id', '=', '1')->firstOrFail();
My only concern now is that it prints as:
   {"company_name":"NOMBRE DE EMPRESA"}

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `->first()` to select the first value from the returned set?

Comment: And if you have more than one entry in your settings, you can perhaps use `->where($id, $_COOKIE["SessionId"])` and add a `SessionID` column to your table.

Comment: That returns with a "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-think your DB schema.

But if you want an answer to keep working with you current schema:

```
DB::table('settings')->select('company_name')->first();
```

This can throw an Eloquent ModelNotFound exception.

**EDIT**

```
public function __construct()
{ 
     $result = DB::table('settings')->select('company_name')->first()->toArray();

     return View::share($result);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. It actually returns with an errorBadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail()

Comment: You're right, @LucasGomez! I learnt something today! The [query builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php) doesn't have that method. One more reason to use Eloquent. Use the `->first()` method instead.

Comment: Yup, I was reading it works only when using Eloquent models, which I actually am, for this settings (update mostly). Using first(); returns "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: Went ahead and made it like this: $company_name = Setting::where('id', '=', '1')->firstOrFail();

It works now, but it prints the whole thing: "{"id":1,"company_name":"Sabores No Colombianos","created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"2014-04-14 15:25:32"}"

Comment: @LucasGomez Try `Setting::where('id', '=', '1')->select('company_name')->firstOrFail();`